# Rotate a rotation matrix about what would be the pitch Euler angle

Tags: android, math, opengl-es

I've got my 3D scene's camera rotating as desired, but to do it I converted to Euler angles using `SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrixIn, eulerAnglesOut);` so I could add 90 to the pitch before recalculating a rotation matrix from the modified Euler angles. I'm adding 90 to the pitch so my rotation can be used for a cubemap where Y is up when the phone is held perpendicular to the ground.

I'm using Euler angles because this made it intuitive to rotate the pitch by 90 degrees. But I'm suffering from gimbal lock now when the phone is held near vertical and the pitch approaches -90 or 90 degrees. The view rapidly rotates 180 degrees (in the roll and azimuth axes) when it gets close to these angles. This does not occur when I use the unmodified rotation matrix, but then I don't have the orientation corrections I need.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the math needed to skip the Euler angles conversion and directly rotate the rotation matrix by 90 degrees about what would be the X axis in Euler angles and invert the roll. I have access to various math classes from a library (Matrix and Quaternion) which can be multiplied by each other and convert to and from Eulers.

I want to rotate about what would be the X axis. Is there a way to do this without introducing gimbal lock?

To clarify: the Euler angles I'm talking about are in -Z, X, Y order, where X is the pitch.

Comment: Oops I meant post-multiply, sorry. That would depend on which convention you use though - that of OpenGL or DirectX

Answer (score 0):

As @meowgoesthedog stated in a deleted comment, the rotation matrix should be pre-multiplied by a matrix that holds a 90 degree rotation about the X axis.

The rotation matrix from Android's sensors converts device orientation to world orientation, so pre-multiplying it by some other matrix is like applying a rotation to the device first before converting the coordinate system.

I was also tripped up by Android's row-major matrix ordering. The matrix must be inverted to get it into OpenGL's column-major ordering. My Euler angles worked OK because they were hiding this inconsistency.